# patching using purely WIX

Tags: wix, patch, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am struggling with creating a patch purely using WIX and I was hoping if someone could guide me in the right direction.

I have a few hundred source files and I run heat against them to create a harvest file followed by creating a package using candle and light.

I need to change a few configuration files and I create a 2nd package with the changes.

Using Torch and pyro I create the .wixmst file and then when trying to create the msp file, pyro complains with the following error.

pyro.exe : error PYRO0252 : No valid transforms were provided to attach to the patch. Check to make sure the transforms you passed on the command line have a matching baseline authored in the patch. Also, make sure there are differences between your target and upgrade.

my question really is: what should patch.wxs contain?

Here is what my patch.wxs looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <Patch 
        AllowRemoval="yes"
        Manufacturer="sample llc" 
        MoreInfoURL="sample.com"
        DisplayName="Env Patch" 
        Description="Env Specfic Patch" 
        Classification="Update"
        >

        <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM" />
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="EnvPatchFamily" />
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>    
        <PatchFamily Id='EnvPatchFamily' Version='1.0.0.0' ProductCode="PUT-GUID-HERE" Supersede='yes' >

            ********************************************** 
                What component Ref should I put in here
                heat creates a component group and I can't
                put ComponentGroupRef in here
            **********************************************

    </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I am using Wix patching as described in this link:
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm

However, it doesn't consider source wix file created using heat.
Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hitesh,

For me heat creates a component group like this:

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MyFiles">
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp2AA1A30564C621322ECB3CDD70B1C03C" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp788C978F16E473D4FD85720B5B75C207" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

heat command:

```
"%WIX%\bin\heat.exe" dir slndir\bin\Release -cg MyFiles -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -dr INSTALLDIR -out ..\Wix\MyFiles.wxs -var var.BinOutputPath -nologo -v -ke  -t wixtransform.xsl
```

And in patch.wxs:

```
<Fragment>    
    <PatchFamily Id='ProductPatchFamily' Version='1.3.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp2AA1A30564C621322ECB3CDD70B1C03C" />
        <ComponentRef Id="cmp788C978F16E473D4FD85720B5B75C207" />
    </PatchFamily>
</Fragment>
```

**Take care: there is no ProductCode attribute in PatchFamily tag**

Comment: Yup you are right about the ProductCode and I removed it. But my question really was what I should be putting in the PatchFamily element, which I figured out that it should contain nothing. Nevertheless thanks for responding. I am going to accept your answer for pointing out to remove ProductCode attribute. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and missed the fact that patch.wxs was hidden. If you left it empty the patch will upgrade all the different files. Otherwise it will upgrade only what you choose.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to mention that `PatchFamily` elements are optional when building a patch, and are intended to allow fine grained control over exactly what will get patched. In most cases I find that I want to include all differences between 2 versions of an MSI when building a patch, in which case I omit the `PatchFamily` altogether. In your case, the resulting patch WXS would look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch 
        AllowRemoval="yes"
        Manufacturer="sample llc" 
        MoreInfoURL="sample.com"
        DisplayName="Env Patch" 
        Description="Env Specfic Patch" 
        Classification="Update"
    >
        <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM" />
        </Media>
    </Patch>
</Wix>
```

I hope this answer helps anyone with a similar question, that is **not** wanting to manually construct patch families, **not** wanting to manually include`ComponentRef` every time they need to build a patch.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the fix for this error is to add the GUID to the component and it should remain same for both the versions of msi.

```
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixPatch" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixPatch" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
         <Component Id="File1" **Guid="3A64BE7A-BBEC-40AD-8319-45C602734146"**>
     <File Source="D:\V2\File1.txt" Name="File1" KeyPath="yes" DiskId="1" Id="F1"/>
         </Component>

</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```